# (High school statistics) Expected value of a probability table

Tags: probability, expectation

So I have a probability table with the values and their probabilities:
$$\begin{array}{|l|l:l|} \hline X & 0    &    1    &   2   &  3  &  4\textsf{ or more} \\ \hdashline \mathsf P_{\!X} &
0.49  &   0.35  &  0.12  &  0.03  &  0.01 \\ \hline \end{array}$$
How would I find the expected value? I know you would take the probability and multiply it by the value and do this for all the values to find the expected value and that works for 1, 2 and 3, but I'm not sure what to do when it comes to '4 or more' because thats a range of values. What would I need to do to find the expected value?

Thanks.(Sorry about formatting, probabilities and what they align with go from left to right respectively (ed: it's now in a MathJax table for you))

Comment: You cannot find the expected value with the given information. You can find a range of possible values for the expected value but not its exact value.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you *do* need to assign a single value to the last category so that you may evaluate an expected value.

Rather than the undefinable $\mathsf E(X)$ you may only sensibly discuss $\mathsf E(\min\{X, 4\})$ .

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I appreciate that

Answer (score 3):

Start like this:

Let $X$ be some random variable

$$\begin{array}{|c|l:l|}\hline
x & \mathsf P(X=x) & x\,\mathsf P(X=x) \\
\hline
0 & 0.49 & 0.00  \\
1 & 0.35 & 0.35  \\
2 & 0.12 & 0.24 \\
3 & 0.03 & 0.09 \\ \hdashline
\gt 4 & 0.01 & >0.04 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

When it comes to four or more you need to specify a range or an upper limit

Comment: I am not the downvoter. I think the downvote is linked to $0.04$ where $x>4$. Graham repaired it now.

Comment: No, the downvote, was linked to to x=1, x=2, x=3, x=4, x>4 and not x=0, x=1, x=2 and so on...

Comment: @Stef Yes that's it as I put 4 then >4 but OP asking for 4 or more my mistake misread it sorry

Comment: @Stef $x=0$ can be looked at as irrelevant in this context of calculating expectation.

Comment: @drhab He had a mistake in copying the probabilities. He started from x=1 to x=4 and then x>4 instead of x=0 to x=3 and x>4... be more careful please

Comment: @BLAZE No, problem I removed the downvote as soon as you corrected it!